# Qt show message box with text input

Tags: qt, pyqt

Is there any easy and clean way to show a message box in Qt4 (PyQt4 actually) with support for text input rather than just selecting a button from a predefined list? I can (and have partially) done this by writing a custom class just for displaying such dialogs but isn't there a cleaner way?

EDIT: I got it working thanks to Luca Carlon. However just in case someone else needs this, I'll post working PyQt4 code here below

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QInputDialog
#This code works only inside a method of a widget or window as self must refer to a
#valid widget or window to get the correct modality, although we can give None instead
(text,truth)=QInputDialog.getText(self,"Get text","User name",QLineEdit.Normal,"NoName")
if truth:
    #The user has accepted the edit, he/she has clicked OK
    print text
else:
    #The user has not accepted the edit, he/she has clicked Cancel
    print "No change"
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, saved me more looking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use QInputDialog for that. The static method getText might be sufficient for you.